# Add new inputs to form after HTTP request

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to add some more fields in my form made by AngularJS, I can't put my complete form, because it's too long, but this is my codes:
JS:

```
this.selectService = function( sid ) {
            this.buffer.service = sid;
            this.buffer.serviceFields = '';
            this.buffer.serviceCost = 0;
            this.fs.order.amount = 0;
            $http({
                url: document.URL,
                method: 'POST',
                data: {
                    'wpo-action': 'get_service_details',
                    'service_id': sid
                }
            }).success( function( data ) {
                if ( data.resp != false )
                    ctrl.buffer.serviceFields = data.html;

                ctrl.buffer.serviceCost = data.cost;
            } ).error( function() {
                alert( 'Failed!' );
            } );
            this.updateTotal();
        };
```

Response for example:

`{"resp":true,"cost":"3500","html":"\t\tPayPal ID<span class=\"important-node\">*<\/span>: <br>\r\n\t\t<input ng-model=\"form.fs.order.extra.n0\" type=\"text\" name=\"order_details[extra][0]\" value=\"\" class=\"wpo-extra-field\">\r\n\t\t<br>\r\n\t\t"}`

ng-model isn't working here.
What's the problem?

I hope my question is good this time, I've tried too much and I can't ask better than this.

Comment: are you returning html in response?

Comment: @khizarnaeem Yes, I wrote an example response in question.

Comment: if you check console in dev tools do you see nonassign error? if its there that means you can't do it this way. you'll have to return some id instead of html and will have to store templates locally to access them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call your server to get html and you want to inject it on your web page ?

Useful doc : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

> Compiles an HTML string or DOM into a template and produces a template function, which can then be used to link scope and the template together.

You have to compile "data.html" in your success function so you can bind a model to your input balise.

(If it does not fit you, please give us more informations about your problem)